# How do I make the following articles collapse within the month?

Tags: php

In the link https://www.queenmypawn.com/archives/, the posts are displayed under the month.

However, I would like to collapse the posts within the month, such as in https://boldanddetermined.com/archives/.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This won't be a PHP thing, but either a HTML or a Javascript thing. What you're describing is an accordion. You can do this either with a standard accordion JS library, or, by using the summary/details HTML tags https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_details.asp, just know that what you're wanting to do is not good for accessibility, and is more difficult to scan/skim. Personally I prefer what you already have

Comment: It's not difficult to make an accordion accessible - you can do simple things like use `details` and `summary` tags and style them. But you'll likely need to know how to code, and where to put the code.